# cast struct that not explictly impl a trait to the trait object?

Tags: rust, struct, traits, box

If there is a struct `NotTFoo` has a method called `say_hi` that statifies `TFoo` trait but not explictly impl `TFoo`, is it possible to use `NotTFoo` as a `TFoo` trait object?

```
// the trait
trait TFoo {
    fn say_hi(&self);
}

// NotFoo doesn't explictly implement TFoo, but it has a say_hi same as TFoo's
struct NotTFoo {}

impl NotTFoo {
    fn say_hi(&self) {}
}

// bar is a trait object
struct Bar{
    bar: Option<Box<dyn TFoo>>
}


// the trait bound `NotTFoo: TFoo` is not satisfied
// required for the cast from `NotTFoo` to the object type `dyn TFoo`r
fn main() {
    let not_foo = NotTFoo{};
    let boxed = Box::new(not_foo) as Box<dyn TFoo>; // Error
    let bar = Bar {bar: Some(boxed)};
}
```

Can I cast `NotTFoo` to `dyn TFoo`?

> the trait bound `NotTFoo: TFoo` is not satisfied
> required for the cast from `NotTFoo` to the object type `dyn TFoo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Rust does not use duck-typing or structural-typing to determine if a type implements a trait. It *must* be explicitly declared.